# How to change the text of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button that needs to be dynamically updated from user input but the normal `.val()`, `.text()`, and `.html()` won't work. How can I change the text of a radio button using jQuery or plain JavaScript?

Comment: If you are talking about the label that appears next to the radio button, then it is not part of the radio button. Use `.next` of the corresponding radio button to access the element provided it is enclosed inside a `label` tag or `span`

Comment: aahhh thats frustrating :(.  thx for the answer :)

Comment: Use a <label> next to your radio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button doesn't have text associated with it.

But if you have a `label tag / span tag` next to the radio option. then you can use `.next` to access that element and change its `text/html`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TMmWf/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" /><label>Option 1</label>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" /><span>Option 1</span>
```

**JS:**

```
var $label = $('input[type=radio]').next();
$label.text('Options');
```

Or you can use the below hack to change the text next to radio option. Note that the below code assumes that **text is next to radio option.**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/nFhnH/1/)

```
var isRadioLabel = 0;
$('div').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeName == '#text' && isRadioLabel == 1) {
        isRadioLabel = 2;
    }
    if (isRadioLabel == 2) {
        this.nodeValue = 'Options';
        isRadioLabel = 0;
    }
    if (this.type == 'radio') {
        isRadioLabel = 1;
    } else {
        isRadioLabel = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: <label> is better option and to change text i think its better to use plain vanilla js without much jQuery

Comment: @Abhishek From OP post -> `How can I change the text of a radio button using jQuery or plain JavaScript?` OP tagged it in jQuery..and again why is it bad to use jQuery. And I did mention about using label/span tag if you missed the first part of the answer. And Please share me the plain vanilla JS to achieve the same effect which is neater than the above.

Answer (score 5):

A radio input **does not have text**

All it is is this:

```
<input type="radio" />
```

[image: on and off radio inputs]

Answer (score 3):

If your `<label>` has been properly associated with a particular radio button using the `for` attribute (as it should be)...

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="example" />
    <label for="example">Clickyclick</label>
</form>
```

...you can just search the DOM for it using by the `for` attribute. Using jQuery:

```
<script>
    var yourElement = $("#example");
    var itsLabel = $("[for=" + yourElement.attr("id") + "]"); // <---
    itsLabel.css("color", "red");
</script>
```

Try it [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RQPJ/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in JS.

```
<label id=labId for=labId     onClick="changeText(this.id)">RADIO BUTTON TEXT</label>
<input type=radio />

<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
const stat=["Old Radio Button Label Text","NEW RADIO BUTTON LABEL TEXT"];
let   cptr=0;

function changeText(button_id){
   var el = document.getElementById(button_id);
   el.firstChild.data = stat[cptr^=1];
}
</script>
```